# Why do webpages need to do a 303 redirect?

Tags: redirect, joomla

Is it common that when you need to POST data to your database, that you *need* to perform a redirect to another location in order to give a response?

I believe some joomla components perform a redirect, and was wondering if this is the norm?

```
Scenario: I want to POST data from this page to my database
When: I click submit
Then: I should be taken to the success page
```

When would it be necessary to perform a redirect to the success page instead of loading it initially? I've read on w3.org that a 303 redirect means that the response is contained in another URI, but what would justify redirecting somewhere else in order to get the success page response?

(lol @ trying some behat logic :P)

Tagged Joomla as I'm working with it

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is common, or at least should be. The reason for redirecting after a POST request is to prevent the POST request from being re-sent on a page refresh.